# converting or creating audio file in mp3 or wav

Tags: android, audio

i am recording  user'a voice in android app and later on i am uploading it on the server , but the server accept only .mp3, .wav and .gsm (8000 Hz, mono channel) to play the sound at server and i am using `mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)` so that my file is saved as .3gp.

as the server is 3rd party and we dont have access to it , so i need to convert or record a file either in mp3/ wav or gsm.

but i dont know how can i convert or record a file in mp3 or wav , is there a way in android to do that

so far i am using following code 
               mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

```
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: You haven't stated which codecs the server supports. But if we assume mpeg-1 layer-3, gsm 06.10 and uncompressed PCM, then AMR_NB obviously isn't going to work. Your best bet might be to bundle an mp3 or gsm 06.10 encoder with your app (keep in mind that there may be royalties involved), record uncompressed PCM using the `AudioRecord` class, encode the audio using your bundled encoder and then upload it to the server. If bandwidth isn't a problem you could just slap a RIFF header on the PCM data to get a WAV file and upload that without encoding the data.

Comment: can you tell me how can i get the WAV file from AMR ? in android

Answer (score 0):

**Manifest permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

---

```
private MediaRecorder recorder ;
public static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;
```

---

**use in your startRecording method**

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(SAMPLING_RATE);

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Recorder");
        try{
          if(dir.mkdir()) {
             System.out.println("Directory created");
          } else {
             System.out.println("Directory alreadt exist");
          }
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //String str = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(dir + "/recorded_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp3");

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: i am able to create it but not able to play at server end , i tried downloading tht filed in played in media player but not able to hear anything

Comment: yes its uploading fine and i am able to download the file too

Comment: you are able to download file and there is no sound available .. so there is some error when you upload the file. Please recheck all the process/step ... may be something is skipping from your side

Comment: yeah i just checked the upload file is there on server plus i am getting status ok response without error. and the file i download only gets play  in VLC and not in anyother mediaplayer